# Why Jet OLEDB driver caches my MDB file?

Tags: asp.net, ms-access

I have a Cassini application that uses Access file. Updated installer overwrites both application and database. However, application still sees the old data even after system restart. (Also copied MDB file manually to make sure it's replaced but it doesn't help.)

The only way for the application to see new MDB data is to install it to a new folder.

Connection string is standard (I think):

```
Connection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + 
    HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("App_Data\\" +
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("dbfile")) + ";Jet OLEDB:Database Password=xxxx";
```

Any idea what's going on and how to avoid the caching issue?

**Update** (to answer some questions in comments):

- We can reproduce this issue only on Windows 7.
- MDB is never updated by the Cassini application. We create database and send it to users. - We did make sure that file was successfully replaced by installer. Actually the same thing happens if we replace it manually.
- The problem remains after Windows reboot.

Comment: What OS are you working with?  Is it Vista or Win7?

Comment: How long does the data remains stale? I've had issues with Jet caching in VB6 apps before, but it was related to writes that were not being flushed quickly enough.

Comment: @m0sa So, you have a running web application, and you want to run an installer to update it. Exactly what operations does your installer perform prior to replacing the .mdb file? Do you stop the web application? Do you stop the IIS service? And then, what do you mean by "system restart"? (What we usually mean by this is "reboot windows".) Also, please do answer mwolfe02's question, it is important.

Comment: The scenario i noticed is that there are 2 IIS sites accessing the same mdb file from different application pools. Once 1 site updates sumething in the mdb file the updates are not immediately visible to the second process.

Comment: I just updated question to answer questions asked.

Comment: Looks like you're installing the DB to App_Data folder in an IIS application?  Any chance this stuff is getting copied into either the GAC or IIS's compiled page cache?  What happens if you install the DB into a folder outside of the website's application directory?  (I'm guessing you've got multiple copies of it floating around)

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to solution Explorer
2. Select mdb file
3. Go to properties, there is one property
4. Do not copy set it to Copy if newer

Answer (score 0):

Set the 
Cache Authorization property of connection object to false which is by default true.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140022(v=office.10).aspx

Comment: Not sure how authorization caching could affect this as we see stalled data in the application. This property is read-only anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" provider? I believe it comes pre-installed with Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

The new Windows 7/Server 2008 security model presents virtualised copies of files under some conditions for each user.

Are you possibly hitting this design feature that is presenting the stale snapshots to the users after the installation completes? Is it possible the application uses different credentials to the user installing the database?

There is a description of the functionality at [User Account Control Data Redirection](http://blogs.windows.com/windows/archive/b/developers/archive/2009/08/04/user-account-control-data-redirection.aspx). The recommended solution is to use a more appropriate folder for the data

Comment: Never heard about that feature, hard to tell without more info and testing. We've workaround this issue changing MDB file name with each new release. I'm not involved with this project at the moment so don't have more feedback.